# The puzzling thing about \newtoks and the token list

Tags: expansion, token-lists, token

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks \test

\begin{document}

    \test={123}
    \test=\test{666}
    \test=\test{hhh}
    \the\test

\end{document}
```

and the result is: 666 hhh 123, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

My question is: why the result is "666 hhh 123" instead of "123 666 hhh" and why there are spaces between 666 and hhh, as well as hhh and 123?

I'm a beginner in TeX and LaTex and I've got some knowledge about tokens, token lists and \newtoks, but the behavior of the above code really confuses me. What is going on? I hope the experts can give me some advice, and I'd like to thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks \test

\begin{document}

% this assigns 123 to \test and makes a space token (ignored in v mode)
    \test={123}
% this assigns \test to \test (no-op) typesets 666 in a group then a non ignored space
    \test=\test{666}
% this assigns \test to \test (no-op) typesets hhh in a group then a non ignored space
    \test=\test{hhh}
% thistypesets the contents of \test which is 123
    \the\test

\end{document}
```

You don't say, but I guess you are tying to append to the token list

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks \test

\begin{document}

    \test={123}%%%
    \test=\expandafter{\the\test 666}%%%
    \test=\expandafter{\the\test hhh}%%%
    \the\test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

After `\newtoks\test` you can assign something to this token register using the syntax

```
\test={123}
```

(the `=` is optional); the tokens you write between braces should be balanced with respect to `{...}`.

You can ask TeX to deliver the contents of the register using

```
\the\test
```

but there is no direct provision for appending tokens to the already stored contents. One has to exploit the way such assignments are performed. After `\test=` TeX will expand tokens in order to look for the `{` that delimits the token list to be assigned (and TeX will ignore space tokens and `\relax` during the process, but this is just a technicality).

In particular, if you want to *append* tokens, you can do

```
\test=\expandafter{\the\test abc}
```

because TeX will do expansion and `\expandafter` will act on the token immediately following `{`, which in this case is `\the` that will deliver the contents of `\test`.

If you want to *prepend* tokens, you have to use a scratch token register: for instance

```
\toks0={uvw}
\test=\expandafter{\the\toks0\expandafter\space\the\test}
```

What does this do? As before, the first `\expandafter` triggers expansion of `\the`. Now `\the` finds the primitive `\toks` that needs to be followed by a number; `0` is found, but TeX will continue expansion until finding something that cannot be interpreted as a digit; it finds `\expandafter` that jumps over `\space` and expands `\the\test`. Then it will expand `\space` and the resulting token will be ignored because it follows `0`, which will be the number TeX was looking for.

The `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup...}\x` method ensures that the definition of `\x` will disappear as soon as `\x` is expanded, so we're covering our tracks.

There is a simpler method for prepending tokens:

```
\test={123}
\toks0={uvw}
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\test={\the\toks0 \the\test}}\x
```

This works because `\edef` will skip over unexpandable tokens, in this case `\test`, but expands `\the`; however, tokens resulting from `\the<token register>` will not be expanded further in `\edef`.

With e-TeX extensions (available with pdftex, xetex and luatex), you can do without a scratch token register:

```
\test={123}
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\test={\unexpanded{uvw}\the\test}}\x
```

Of course you want to define macros for these jobs:

```
\def\append#1#2{#2=\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\def\prepend#1#2{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    #1={\unexpanded{#2}\the#1}%
  }\x
}

\newtoks\test

\test={123}
\append\test{abc}
\prepend\test{uvw}

\the\test

\bye
```

will print

> uvw123abc

Answer (score 2):

You are doing:

```
\test={123}       % the value 123 is saved to \test
\test=\test{666}  % \test=\test (assigning similar to a=a) is done,
                  % then 666 is printed in group
\test=\test{hhh}  % \test=\test is done and then hhh is printed in group
\the\test         % the value of \test, i.e. 123, is expandend and printed
```